# Test into the book Halliday-Resnick on scalar product and cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, physics, cross-product

1. Two vectors lie with their tails in common in the same place. When the angle between them is increased by $20^\circ$, their scalar product has the same module but changes sign from positive to negative. The initial angle between the vectors was:
   **A** $0^\circ$.
   **B** $60^\circ$.
   **C** $70^\circ$.
   **D** $80^\circ$.
   **E** $90^\circ$.

### My solution:

The scalar product is $$\mathbf{v}\bullet \mathbf{w}=vw\cos \theta$$
I will delete immediately the **A)** the **B**) because $\theta+20^\circ< 90^\circ$; also the **C)** and the **E)** are false because $$\theta+20^\circ= 90^\circ \implies \mathbf{v}\bullet \mathbf{w}=0$$
Hence the **D)** is true. In fact $$\alpha=\theta+20^\circ> 90^\circ$$ and $\cos \alpha<0$.

For another test on cross product I have a bit of difficulty.

2. Two vectors lie with their tails in common in the same place. When the angle between them is increased by $20^\circ$, the module of their vector product doubles. The initial angle between the vectors was:

**A** $0^\circ$.
**B** $18^\circ$.
**C** $25^\circ$.
**D** $45^\circ$.
**E** $90^\circ$.

### Possible solution (?)

$$|\mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{w}|=vw\sin \beta \implies 2vw\sin \beta=vw\sin(\beta+20^\circ)$$

Did I interpret the assignment correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretations are correct indeed. The answer to the first question is $80^\circ$ because $\cos(100^\circ)=-\cos(80^\circ)$.

On the other hand, none of the options for the other question is exactly correct. The closest one is $18^\circ$, since$$\frac{\sin(38^\circ)}{\sin(18^\circ)}\approx1.992.$$

Comment: Very kind Prof. with a lot of sincerity, I am very tired into my school, conferences online with Google Suite (reason Covid) I have my mind shakered. Why $\cos(100^\circ)=-\cos(80^\circ)$? Why in the 2nd part do you use the ratio of the two $\sin$? Is it possible to know if my consideration give the same your answer, please? +1

Comment: For any angle $\theta$,$$\cos(90^\circ+\theta)=\cos(90^\circ)\cos(\theta)-\sin(90^\circ)\sin(\theta)=-\sin(\theta)$$and$$\cos(90^\circ-\theta)=\cos(90^\circ)\cos(\theta)+sin(90^\circ)\sin(\theta)=\sin(\theta);$$in particular, $\cos(90^\circ+\theta)=-\cos(90^\circ-\theta)$. And you were after an angle $\theta$ such that $\sin(20^\circ+\theta)=2\sin(\theta)$. However, this is the same thing as asserting that $\frac{\sin(20^\circ+\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$.

Comment: I don't believe it Prof. that I have done the right exercise aahahha. Approved.

Comment: Thank you veryyyyyyy much.